# Angular 2 how to return from map function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, filereader, angular-httpclient

Angular 2 how to return from map if it has subscription inside

```
getImage(imageId: string): Observable<ImageSource> {

      return this.http.get(`${ImagesUrl}/${imageId}`, { 
        responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' }).map((response) => {
        // here I am converting blob to base64
            let blob = response; // lets say response is blob

            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

            reader.onloadend = (e) => {
              // how can I return from here?????
            };
      }
    }
```

is there a way to return from map only after onloadend event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know FileReader class, but you can try to chain all the things you have to do (utilize streams).

```
function getImage(imageId: string): Observable<ImageSource> {
  return this.http.get(`${ImagesUrl}/${imageId}`, {responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'})
      .switchMap((response) => {
        const blob = response;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

        return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reader.onloadend = resolve;
        }));
      });
}
```

`reader.onloadend = resolve;` is a shorthand for

```
reader.onloadend = (e) => { resolve(e); }
```

At the end of stream you will get event published by `onloadend`. If you need anything else, just pass another argument to resolve.

You should also handle case when something fails with `reject`.